# Примеры использования функций-конструкторов

Tags: javascript

С теорией функций-конструкторов я с бОльшего разобрался. Непонятно только одно: где конкретно их использование оправдано и необходимо. Хотя бы 5 конкретных примеров проектов, где без них не обойтись.

Comment: Конструкторы реализуют наследование - один из базовых аспектов ООП. Обойтись без ООП вы можете всегда, в любом проекте. Дело лишь в том, что другими способами задача может решаться гораздо сложнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция конструктор(ES5) - это класс(ES6).

Примеров использования очень много - например при создании конструктора с методами и прототипами.

В итоге у вас получится готовый "инструмент", который внутри себя сможет делать какие-либо манипуляции с передаваемыми аргументами.

Примеров, как я уже написал выше, очень много - вы можете взять неминифицированную версию библиотеку `jQuery` и посмотреть как там используется функция-конструктор.

Если говорить об элементарных примерах, то, например, нативный конструктор `Array`, вы хотите дописать метод, который будет возвращать значение, получая индекс, вы делаете так:

```
Array.prototype.getValueByIx = function(index) {
    return this[index];
}
```

Вызов:

```
var value = [1,2,3].getValueByIx(1);
console.log(value); // на выходе - 2
```